# Field Collections not displaying in Content Template

Tags: theming, nodes, entities

I'm using [Content Templates (Contemplate)](https://drupal.org/project/contemplate) module to style a node display for a content type that uses [Field Collections](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection). When I view the node's display page before changing anything in the Content Template, the Field Collections display fine. As soon as I tick the "Affect body output" checkbox to adjust the template, the Field Collection content no longer shows up on the display. The header is there, but the content is gone.

How can I get the Field Collection content to display? Is there an incompatibility issue with Content Templates and Field Collections?

This is a Drupal 7 site... and, before you ask, I need to use Content Templates for theming due to a somewhat locked down development environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily an answer, but a viable workaround:

The Field Collection content is available to views, so I made a view block that prints out the Field Collection content where the contextual relationship is the node's NID. That block gets displayed on this content type only. With some Javascript trickery, I'll be able to position it where it needs to go.

I'm open to a real answer, but for now, this is all I've got.